# Parse website from Wikipedia Infobox data

Tags: python, parsing, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I am using wikipedia api to fetch infobox data. I want to parse `website url` from this infobox data. I tried using [mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) to parse website url, but there are different formats for different keywords.

Here are few patterns for website -

```
url                  = <!-- {{URL|www.example.com}} -->
| url = [https://www.TheGuardian.com/ TheGuardian.com]
| url = <span class="plainlinks">[https://www.naver.com/ www.naver.com]</span>
|url             = [https://www.tmall.com/ tmall.com]
|url            = [http://www.ustream.tv/ ustream.tv]
```

I need help in parsing `official website link`  for all the patterns supported by wikipedia?

**Edit -**

*Code -*

```
# get infobox data
import requests
# keyword
keyword = 'stackoverflow.com'
# wikipedia api url
api_url = (
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&'
    'rvprop=content&titles=%s&rvsection=0&format=json' % keyword)
# api request
resp = requests.get(api_url).json()
page_one = next(iter(resp['query']['pages'].values()))
revisions = page_one.get('revisions', [])
# infobox daa
infobox_data = next(iter(revisions[0].values()))

# parse website url
import mwparserfromhell
wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(infobox_data)
templates = wikicode.filter_templates()
website_url_1 = ''
website_url_2 = ''
for template in templates:
    # Pattern - `URL|http://x.com`
    if template.name == "URL":
        website_url_1 = str(template.get(1).value)
        break
    if not website_url_1:
        # Pattern - `website = http://x.com`
        try:
            website_url_2 = str(template.get("website").value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    if not website_url_1:
        # Pattern - `homepage = http://x.com`
        try:
            website_url_2 = str(template.get("homepage").value)
        except ValueError:
            pass
if website_url_1:
    website_url = website_url_1
elif website_url_2:
    website_url = website_url_2
```

Comment: Can you show your code? mwparserfromhell should be able to deal with all of these (except the first which won't actually display a link).

Comment: @Tgr added code I am using. It covers only few cases.

Answer (score 0):

One can parse the patterns you've mentioned using a regex and BeautifulSoup. It's conceivable that one might parse additional patterns by extending this approach.

I remove the stuff that includes 'url = ' from the beginning of a line and then use BeautifulSoup to deal with the remainder. Since BeautifulSoup encapsulates what it's given to form a complete page the original content can be obtained as the text of the `body` element.

```
>>> import re
>>> patterns = '''\
... url                  = <!-- {{URL|www.example.com}} -->
... | url = [https://www.TheGuardian.com/ TheGuardian.com]
... | url = <span class="plainlinks">[https://www.naver.com/ www.naver.com]</span>
... |url             = [https://www.tmall.com/ tmall.com]
... |url            = [http://www.ustream.tv/ ustream.tv]'''
>>> import bs4
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\s*\|?\s*url\s*=\s*', re.I)
>>> for pattern in patterns.split('\n'):
...     soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(re.sub(regex, '', pattern), 'lxml')
...     if str(soup).startswith('<!--'):
...         'just a comment'
...     else:
...         soup.find('body').getText()
... 
'just a comment'
'[https://www.TheGuardian.com/ TheGuardian.com]'
'[https://www.naver.com/ www.naver.com]'
'[https://www.tmall.com/ tmall.com]'
'[http://www.ustream.tv/ ustream.tv]'
```

Comment: Thanks, this can be useful if someone can provide a comprehensive list of patterns. I've checked data of few hundred pages and I didn't find any standard set of patterns.

Comment: I need more specific solution to parse `website` from wikipedia api data. Anything on those lines will help.

Comment: I assumed you had done your research into what other people know of this. There is no standard pattern or comprehensive set of patterns. Nonetheless, you might still be able to extend this yourself in a useful way.

Answer (score 0):

[mwparserfromhell](https://github.com/earwig/mwparserfromhell) is a good tool for this:

```
import mwclient
import mwparserfromhell

site = mwclient.Site('en.wikipedia.org')
text = site.pages[pagename].text()
wikicode = mwparserfromhell.parse(text)
templates = wikicode.filter_templates(matches='infobox .*')
url = templates[0].get('url').value

url_template = url.filter_templates(matches='url')
url_link = url.filter_external_links()
if url_template:
    print url_template[0].get(1)
elif url_link:
    print url_link.url
else:
    print url
```

Comment: This code -`url = templates[0].get('url').value`  doesn't work in all the cases. eg. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Institute_of_Technology,_Karnataka
There is no standard attribute for url in data. I found `website, url and homepage` from my observations. Do you know all the valid attribute names?

Comment: No. You might have more luck asking that kind of question on Wikipedia (the [technical village pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Village_pump_(technical)) for example).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/urigoren/3d373d442c5fc68c4f6818c9b7d8f0d0), that might be helpful:

```
import collections
import wikipedia
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def infobox(wiki_page):
    """Returns the infobox of a given wikipedia page"""
    if isinstance(wiki_page, str):
        wiki_page = wikipedia.page(wiki_page)
    try:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(wiki_page.html()).find_all("table", {"class": "infobox"})[0]
    except:
        return None
    ret = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    section = ""
    for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
        th = tr.find_all("th")
        if not any(th):
            continue
        th = th[0]
        if str(th.get("colspan"))=='2':
            section = th.text.translate({160:' '}).strip()
            continue
        k = th.text.translate({160:' '}).strip()
        try:
            v = tr.find_all("td")[0].text.translate({160:' '}).strip()
            ret[section][k] = v
        except IndexError:
            continue
    return dict(ret)
```